# VBA macro only able to run once partially

Tags: html, excel, vba, registry

I modified a code I found online to be able to find a ClassName on an HTML page and returns its text when doing a Google search. I need to do this for about 10,000 companies and was able to get it to work but when testing it with only 100 rows it stops around ~60th row. After that I am unable to get any results and found the only way to resolve it is by running a registry cleaner. I tested this on another computer and had the same results.

I'm very new to VBA so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub GoogleSearch()
Dim URL As String
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument

Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
'Set htmlDoc = New HTMLDocument

Dim objResults1 As Object
Dim objResults2 As Object
Dim objResults3 As Object

On Error Resume Next

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To lastRow

URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(I, 1)

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With objHTTP
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
    htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

End With

Set objResults1 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("YhemCb")
Set objResults2 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("wwUB2c kno-fb-ctx")
Set objResults3 = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("LC20lb")

Cells(I, 2) = objResults1(0).innerText
Cells(I, 3) = objResults2(0).innerText
Cells(I, 4) = objResults3(0).innerText

Next

Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set objResults1 = Nothing
Set objResults2 = Nothing
Set objResults3 = Nothing
Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: AntonioF, if possible, could you please provide some of the input you're feeding into the program? There might be something in the ~60th row that provokes this(?)

Comment: Col A would have a company name such as "Werner Sobek New York Corp". B2 would return "Engineering consultant in New York City, New York", C2 would be blank (thats fine), and D2 would return "Werner Sobek New York | Werner Sobek". As for why it happens around the 60th row I am not sure, I've tried it several times with different sets of companies names and each time it would stop around the 60th row and not be able to run again.